# Android Webview Crash report on Galaxy s10 and note10

Tags: android, android-webview, google-play-console

Google play console reported this webview crash.

backtrace:
#00  pc 00000000017db2dc  /system/app/WebViewGoogle/WebViewGoogle.apk!libmonochrome.so (offset 0x15b000)

This is all log I have from Play console.
Does anyone have a solution with it?

It was really hard to find a solution specially with webview error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add crashlytics or another tool for crash reports. That way you will be able to get the stacktrace and details about the crash. It is actually pretty easy, follow the steps on this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) This way you will be able to get a better report and solve your error or ask a more detailed question so we can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I already added crashlytics and my app is a web app so when webview error occurs, even crashlytic can't catch the error. I guess webview error occurs before crashlytics is activated.

is there any other suggestion?